# Convert formatted plain text to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of data formatted like this, which displays great in a pre-tag:

```
1: Here's my first row, and it is
   quite long...
   and can span over several rows.
2: This is the second row.
```

However, I'd like to have some control of it and maybe make it into html:

```
<ol>
    <li>Here's my first row, and it is<br/>quite long...<br/>and can span over several rows.</li>
    <li>This is the second row</li>
</ol>
```

I can't seem to find a pre-to-html-converter online. How would I go about it?

Cheers!

Comment: Please show the raw html for your first textblock.

Comment: Do you absolutely need a JavaScript implementation? I believe there's more choice if you can use some server-side language; to begin with, almost any wiki software already contains such library.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets — It isn't HTML, that's the point.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No, I don't need it to be JavaScript. I'm in a .NET-environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual tools for converting text files to HTML are [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29). There are numerous implementations of each (and Wikipedia lists [8 JS implementations of Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Markdown_implementations)).

I doubt either will, out of the box, suit the specific text you have, but their source code should make a reasonable starting point.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have control over the data that comes to me  in plain-text, so I have to cater for several different text-"layouts". I'll look into the implementation of Markdown!

Answer (score 1):

Try a Wiki markup engine [like the one that SO uses](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).